# Sorting an Associative php array by descending order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an associative array, and i have been trying to use multisort and usort to sort it by its **ID** in the descending pattern, instead of descending it always comes in the ascending order. can any body help me on this

how the array looks like

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'ID' => string '105' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'R158' (length=11)
      'accountname' => string 'DDD' (length=3)
      'accountID' => string '1' (length=1)
      'stat' => string '2' (length=1)
      'total_impr' => string '207' (length=3)
      'min(a.timestamp)' => string '2014-05-16 05:38:01' (length=19)
      'max(a.timestamp)' => string '2015-01-22 05:50:41' (length=19)
```

**code multisort**

```
$ID = array();
        foreach ($array_tsb as $key => $row)
        {
                $ID[$key] = $row['ID'];
        }
            array_multisort($ID, SORT_DESC, $array_tsb );
```

code usort

```
function cmp($a, $b)
    {
            return $b['ID'] - $a['ID'];
    }

    usort($array_tsb, "cmp"); //even rsort dint work
```

Comment: looks like your ID is string ... Are you trying to do string sorting or integer sorting ?

Comment: sorry for the delay... integer sorting in descending order

Answer (score 1):

Your array looks like being the result of a database query. In that case, it might be easier to do the sorting in the query via SQL ORDER BY, instead of doing a database task in PHP.